# Javascript regex with fixed string and some variable separated by hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test url similar to this:

```
/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars
```

I want to return `true` for any url that follows the next pattern:

```
/mobile/cars/[Company]-[CarName]-cars
```

- `[Company]` can be any name in `a-z` or `A-Z`
- `[CarName]` also can be composed by any char in `a-z` or `A-Z`

Can someone help me to write a regex to match the above pattern?

My attempt was

```
/mobile\/cars\/[a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z]-cars/.test(text)
```

but no success.

**Test case**

```
/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars : Valid, 

/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/ : Valid, 

/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars-in-city: Invalid
```

Comment: Any attempts toward getting `an exact regex for this`?

Comment: I did but i can't figure out a way to include fixed characters within search pattern. It should be something like: /mobile\/cars\/[a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z]-cars/.test(text)

Comment: Please add that to the question!!!!!!

Comment: You're pretty much completed it already and only missing `+` quantifier - 1 or more - to show that you need more than one letter in your ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Test case:

```
var str = "/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars-in-city";
var patt = new RegExp("\/mobile\/cars\/[A-z\-]+-cars(\/[^-]*)?$");
var res = patt.test(str);
if( res ) {
    //true
}else {
    //false
}
```

Comment: Its almost working. Just one more case i need to ensure.
This should end with '/' OR just at cars.

/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars : Valid,

/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/ : Valid,

/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars-in-city: Invalid

Comment: You need to escape the last `/` - like this `\/?`

Comment: Yes looks like. But why are we using (?"cars)

Even \/mobile\/cars\/[\w]+-[\w]+-cars\/?$ works.

What is the difference?

Comment: Can you explain me the meaning of 
cars(\/[^-]*)?$ expression

Comment: This is capturing group. I don't want this. Since i just want true/false. Can you please modify it and explain the solution a bit.

Comment: I have edited the answer where you get output as only true or not. pls check it.

Comment: @Vegeta: does't use ``[A-z]``, seems a good solutions but it matches any symbols between uppercase and lowercase letters in the ascii table (``[``,``]``,``_``,``^``,``\`` and backtick)

Answer (score 1):

There you are it should match your urls

`\/mobile\/cars\/[\w]+-[\w]+-cars\/?.*$`

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/uQ9qU5/3)

Comment: \/mobile\/cars\/[\w]+-[\w]+-cars$

This seems best to me.

What is difference between [\w] and [a-bA-B]?

Comment: Indeed, you right `+`is better than `*` I'll edit. And there is no difference I think between `[\w]` and `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Sorry, i accepted but even its not the solution:
/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/ : Valid
But the solution shows it as invalid

Comment: /mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/ :  wont wok

Comment: @sahil if the url has a / at his end you'll have to had \/ between cars and $ Like this :
`\/mobile\/cars\/[\w]+-[\w]+-cars\/$`

Comment: /mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars fails.

Comment: So you want to test if there a / or not at the end ? (Accept it in both case ?)
`\/mobile\/cars\/[\w]+-[\w]+-cars\/?$`

Comment: We have one more choice. After cars, we can have anything (example '/' or nothing) but not hyphen ('-'). Updated the question.

Comment: Why would you write `[\w]+` instead of `\w+`? Also, this will include digits and underscores, which were not in the OP's description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
/^[/]mobile[/]cars[/][a-z]+-[a-z]+-cars(?=[/]|$)/i
```

**Legenda**

```
/                  # Start regex js delimiter
  ^                # Match the beginning of the string
  [/]              # Match a literal slash '/' (i prefer this form over '\/')
  mobile           # Match the literal string 'mobile'
  [/]              # as above
  cars             # Match the literal string 'cars'
  [/]              # as above
  (?:              # Start non capturing group 
    [a-z]+-        # One or more of lowercase letters followed by a literal dash '-'
                   # (the ignorecase flag 'i' makes it matches also uppercase ones)
  ){2}             # Exactly two of the above, equivalent to [a-z]+-[a-z]+-
  cars             # Match the literal string 'cars'
  (?=[/]|$)        # Lookahead, cars HAVE to be followed by a slash '/'
                   # or by the end of the string '$'
/i                 # ignore case flag [a-z] match also [A-Z]
```

**Live Demo**

```js
var re = /^[/]mobile[/]cars[/](?:[a-z]+-){2}cars(?=[/]|$)/i;

var tests = ['/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars-whatever-dash-something/slash/a-beautiful-car.html','/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/whatever-dash-something/slash/a-beautiful-car.html','/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/whatever','/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars-in-city','/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars','/mobile/cars/volkswagen-vento-cars/'];
var m;

while(t = tests.pop()) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += '"' + t + '"<br/>';
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += 'Valid URL prefix? ' + ( (t.match(re)) ? '<font color="green">YES</font>' : '<font color="red">NO</font>') + '<br/><br/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```